# ICallingBotService in Botframeowrk SDK v3 is not request aware

Tags: request, skype, botframework

I am developing Skype Calling bout using Microsoft Bot Framework ASK v3. When I configure the call URL of the (skype) bot, I append a query parameter and I need to be able to access this parameter on request to my bot and as a result of this in the events of ICallingBotService. Current SDK does not allow access to the Request data in the event scope.

I think it is natural to provide access to Request data in the event scope since event is called upon request.

Anyway, will appreciate any suggestion how to implement access to Request in the event scope of ICallingBotService.

Answer (score 0):

I created pull request to Microsoft/BotBuilder repository to support missing functionality: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/764